# Dockerfile Run bash file using $PATH from ENV directive

Tags: docker, environment-variables

Bellowing are part of my Dockerfile, I want to set PATH once with ENV, and in the following *.sh file, they don't need to re-define the $PATH.
How to achieve this ?

```
ENV PATH="/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"

RUN /bin/bash -c "source install_anaconda3.sh"

RUN /bin/bash -c "source install_tensorflow.sh"

RUN /bin/bash -c "source install_theano.sh"
```

Inside install_anaconda3.sh it is:

```
#!/bin/bash -
bash "./installer/Anaconda3-5.0.1-Linux-x86_64.sh" -u -b

conda upgrade -y --all
```

Then I got following error:

> /bin/sh: install_anaconda3.sh: command not found

Answer (score 0):

You can set a working directory so the following commands will be running in its context:

```
WORKDIR /usr/local/bin
# run scripts from /usr/local/bin
RUN ./install_anaconda3.sh
RUN ./install_tensorflow.sh
# ...
```

This way you don't need $PATH

Comment: I change to :RUN export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda
RUN export PATH="/root/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
RUN export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"
and I print inside install_anaconda3.sh --> echo "path --> $PATH", the output confirm that it didn't get the correct PATH.

Comment: @huangyingw, as it turned out I was wrong about `ENV` - it actually works and if set environment variable with it - you can access this variable from shell script in another file - and it does not matter how you start the file (directly or with `source` command). I tried all the ways around, but everything works all the time even your original code works fine!

Comment: yes, you are correct, just tried, and it works, great thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

@Pavel Agarkov, I changed to

RUN export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda

RUN export PATH="/root/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"

RUN export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"

RUN /bin/bash -c "source install_anaconda3.sh"
while in install_anaconda3.sh, it still could not get the correct PATH.